# Characters & and < make everything get lost on the way between HttpPost and HttpResponse

Tags: android, http-post, special-characters, httpresponse

I am sending some XML as a SOAP request, but when that XML contains the characters `&` or `<`, I get an empty response. Here is some relevant code:

```
String myXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
               "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                   "<soap12:Body>" +
                      "[XML THAT DOESN'T WORK WITH '&' AND '<']" +
                   "</soap12:Body>" +
               "</soap12:Envelope>";

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website.com");
StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(myXml, HTTP.UTF_8);
stringEntity.setContentType("text/xml");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8)";
httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
BasicHttpResponse httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);

HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = responseEntity.getContent();
//Checking inputStream here reveals that it is empty (not null) when xml has '&' or '<'
```

I thought it might be because of [these predefined entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML), but every other special character that I tried it with caused no problems.

Do you know why this is, and how I can go about fixing it (other than just catching the specific cases of `&` and `<`)?

I found a suggested solution to do

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<NameValuePair>, String encoding))
```

But I don't have `NameValuePair`s, just a `StringEntity`.

Comment: xml specifically does not support <> and &. These 3 entities must be escaped. You can use URLEncoder.encode, for instance (but it encodes much more things, you'll probably have issues with these).

Comment: not just three, they are 5 (you don't mention apostrophe and double quotation mark).

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode` is not for xml data escaping.

Comment: @Arhimed For some reason, > and ' and " do not cause issues in my application. It is only < and &.

Comment: well, we are talking about xml spec, and it states those 5 should be escaped. the fact you don't get issue with all special chars is just a  happy corner case, I believe.

Comment: Your problem comes from the fact that the response you try to process is NOT xml at all. It is the service responsibility to send correct xml. You won't be able to solve this problem on your side unless making your own parser code to handle incorrect xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it might be because of these predefined entities

Exactly. Those should be escaped for values, so the correct version of the data would be:

```
[XML THAT DOESN'T WORK WITH '&amp;' AND '&lt;']
```

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, am I supposed to look at the XML list or the HTML list? If it's the XML list I guess I'll just make a function to catch those five characters.

Comment: Yes, just create a "filter" function to substite all occurrences of those 5 chars with their escaped versions.

Comment: Also you can try to use `XmlSerializer` from Android API. For instance, its `text(String text)` writes text, where special XML chars are escaped automatically. But I think it's faster to implement your own custom filter solution, than studying how to properly use `XmlSerializer`. :)